# Facebook and Firebase Authentication in Angular2

Tags: facebook, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I found some troubles with firebase and facebook authentication using Angular2. I´ve created this method to verify with the console if the user is logged in but I think this isn´t the correct way to do this because the console is not reporting me the correct values.

So here is my code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
    if (this.user)
      console.log('NOT LOGGED');
    else
      console.log('LOGGED IN', this.afAuth.authState);
  }

  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
  }

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

How can I use the user observable in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `authState` returns an observable you need to subscribe to get the value:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
    if (auth) {
      console.log('LOGGED IN', auth);
    } else {
      console.log('NOT LOGGED');
  }
}
```